# Using imagegick with php to resize

Tags: php, imagemagick

I downloaded ImageMagick expecting to use it to resize images on my website like phpthumb use to do before the function are deprecated. But the fact is that i am not finding anywhere how to use it to resize en image with PHP code.
I see some command line but i want to resize using some php code
Thanks for helping

Comment: If you want to resize an image with php, you can use the GD library and more specifically the imagecopyresampled function.

Comment: SO, going to php website and looking for [examples](http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.examples-1.php) somehow eluded you. Or even using google and searching for `php ImageMagick` produce nothing. That's sad :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you can resize images with imagemagik. PHP has a wrapper class. Check this https://github.com/avalanche123/Imagine and this http://imagine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage/introduction.html#resize-images. You can go with GD library if needs are minimal with images.